# Bad juju with for/in loop

Tags: javascript

I have a small script that looks like this:

```
hideElements = arguments.shift().split ( ',' );
for ( iterator in hideElements ) { 
    console.log ('  --> hiding ' + hideElements[iterator] );
    lg_transitions ( {kind:"slide-up"} , { target : hideElements[iterator] } );
}
```

When I run it in the debugger all things start quite rationally. I put a breakpoint at the first line listed above. After pressing the "step over next function call" button to initialise the "hideElements" variable to the following:

[image]

This is what is what I would have expected but then after completing the first (and should be the only) iteration it comes back to the head of the loop and the "iterator" which had started at 0 has now strangely changed to "remove". Huh? No idea where that came from. But in the console.log message that follows there might be a hint ... it prints the following to the console:

[image]

This is a function called -- you guessed it -- "remove". It is a function that I added recently for a different reason but it is not called directly or indirectly and so I'm at a loss as to why this would be picked up here. For anyone interested in the full code for "remove", here it is:

```
// Array Remove - By John Resig (MIT Licensed)
Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {
   var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
   this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
   return this.push.apply(this, rest);
}
```

ADDITION:

The code I had neglected to add earlier was the initialisation of the arguments array. Here's what I had (note I've since changed the name to "args" instead of arguments):

```
function ConditionalFormatting ( key , eventObject , setOfRules ) {
console.log ("Entering conditional formatting: key is " + key + ", eventObject is " + eventObject.attr('id') + ", setOfRules is " + setOfRules );
var ruleStrings = [];
ruleStrings = setOfRules.split (';');
var targetOverride = false;
jQuery.each ( ruleStrings , function ( i , ruleString ) {
    // There is a rule, now let's find out which one
    var targetElement;
    var args = [];
    args = ruleString.split('::');
    var rule = args.shift();
```

Comment: sidenote: don't do `for ... in` on arrays.

Comment: `for...in` iterates over the properties of an object. This includes any functions they might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `arguments` object is not an actual array. Therefore it doesn't have the `shift()` function. If you want the first object in the array, obtain the element at index 0 (first object). Moreover, use a regular for loop to traverse the arguments object.

```
hideElements = arguments[0].split(',');

for ( var i = 0; i < hideElements.length; i++ ) {
    ...
}
```

`arguments` is not a real array, however, if you wish to use it like it were an array, then use `Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments );`:

```
if ( arguments.length > 0)
    hideElements = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments ).shift();
```

From there on you can use hideElements as an array.

Comment: Thanks David. I'm surprised that I haven't had this problem earlier. Just wondering, if I use a conditional wrapper of -- if (arguments.length>0) {hideElements=arguments.shift(); } -- would that be considered safe? The reason is I like popping off elements off the arguments stack. It seems to work in other cases. If that's ok then I would clearly need to replace the for/in with a traditional for as you suggest.

Comment: @ken It's fine, but remember that you can't use `.shift()` on the arguments object. But there's a way to turn it into a real array by using `Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments );`. I'll edit with the details.

Comment: I'm still learning things all the time with JS and in this case ... just to add a twist ... I didn't realise the significance of the built in Javascript "arguments" object and actually had declared a local variable called arguments which is what this was operating on. Anyway, let me take my new-found wisdom back to the editor and see I can get this problem solve. Thanks again.

Comment: @ken What did you set that local variable `arguments` to?

Comment: I've added the top of the function to the question above including the  initialisation of the "arguments" array.

Comment: @ken My fault. I thought you had overridden the `arguments` object with a local variable named "arguments". But in your code it was simply named "args". Silly me. Never mind. :)

Comment: No you are correct. I just renamed it to "args" now based on our conversation.

Comment: interestingly even with the "args" name change I still have the same issue. I'm going to change the for/in loop now but in the past this always used to work ... fingers crossed.

Comment: @ken I see the problem. Instead of doing `args = ruleString.split('::');` (if you want to add to the array) do this: `args.push( ruleString.split('::') );`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19362/discussion-between-ken-and-david)

Answer (score 1):

@Yoshi is right: `for in` will list all fields in the object - which is what the array actually is.

Try using the [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method:

```
hideElements = arguments.shift().split ( ',' );
for (iterator in hideElements ) { 
    if (hideElements.hasOwnProperty(iterator))
    {
        console.log ('  --> hiding ' + hideElements[iterator] );
        lg_transitions ( {kind:"slide-up"} , { target : hideElements[iterator] } );
    }
}
```

This is why you should usually avoid using `for in` to iterate over arrays and use a normal `for` loop instead. jsHint/[jsLint](http://www.jslint.com/) will give you a message like this for the code you posted:

```
The body of a for in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype.
```

---

Sidenote:

`for (iterator in hideElements )` will create a global variable `iterator`, while `for (var iterator in hideElements )` won't.

Comment: The sidenote might be a bit misleading. As even with `var` `iterator` would be global if the whole loop would be run in global scope. That is to say, javascript has no block scope.

Comment: @Yoshi Since he's using `arguments` I'm assuming that the code is inside a function.